# reason for obtaining NaN in Pearson correlation of Matlab

Tags: matlab, correlation

I would like to know what reasons could be for obtain NaN in Matlab's corr function (Pearson type). If I use the same vectors with Spearman, it returns a number, but not with Pearson.

Thanks,

Comment: I got NaN in pearson correlation when the vectors you are evaluating do not have a similar profile - if they are really not correlated, then it outpts NaN. Otherwise you should get a value

Comment: Try this test:
vectorA = [1:100];
vectorB = [101:200];

correlate both. It should be something around 0.99

Comment: Maybe it is because the vectors are too small? With 10 length goes wrong and with 1000 goes fine, small, but not NaN. Anyway, maybe it is also because of my vectors nature

Comment: What is your vectors nature? how do they look like?

Comment: Well, the other problem can be because I am making a mess with the vectors length and meaning. But the strange part is that only changing the length (being the same vectors) changes the NaN part to a number.